# program opening multiple processes

Tags: process, filemanager, dolphin

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and am using KDE Dolphin as my file manager.  It works just fine.  I did however notice that it is now running in multiple processes.  It is as if every time I go to a new folder a new process opens.  This never happened before.  I have been using Dolphin this way since 11.04.  It always ran in a single process.  I searched and I can't seem to find out why it is suddenly doing this or how to get it to run in a single process again.  I tried the KDE user wiki to no avail.  I can't tell if the issue is a from Dolphin or Ubuntu.  There was no upgrade at the time aside from the usual Ubuntu updates that did not include Dolphin.  I do know Windows has a setting to change whether Windows Explorer opens in a single or multiple process.  Is there something like that in Ubuntu?

Comment: By process, do you mean windows? How exactly are you determining that it is in fact multiple processes?

Comment: I open System Monitor and it's listed in the Process tab.  There used to be only one listed. Now there can be 25 or even 50.  The CPU% are typically 0 for them but there should only be one listed in the tab.  If I open Dolphin with System Monitor open only one instance is listed.  Every time I open a folder, one to two more show up in the Process listing.  If I end any one of them all close and Dolphin is terminated.  The same does not happen with Nautilus.  That still runs as only one process.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer in a Kbuntu forum in the following thread:

"Konqueror and Dolphin are creating Zombies!"

Dolphin was leaving zombie processes behind as I moved from folder to folder. (It took me a while to realize that they were called "zombie processes").

I followed what **stychokiller** posted on May 25th 2014 and fixed the problem by deleting `.kde/share/config/dolphinrc`

https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?65569-Konqueror-and-Dolphin-are-creating-Zombies!&p=351866&viewfull=1#post351866

---

**UPDATE:** Unfortunately the above solution only seems to work if I don't reconfigure Dolphin. With the default `dolphinrc` file I did not get any zombies. I then reconfigured Dolphin the way I wanted it and and it's leaving zombie processes in it's wake again.